# Как реализовать в Telegram боте на Python, чтобы он брал посты со словом Whyred с определённых каналов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот

необходимо сделать так чтобы когда на определённых телеграмм канале делается пост с указанным словом бот уведомлял пользователя

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём? Вы не знаете, как создавать ботов, или не знаете, как проверить наличие определённого слова в строке?

Comment: Я же описал, пишу бота, необходимо сделать так чтобы когда на определённых телеграмм канале делается пост с указанным словом бот уведомлял пользователя

Comment: Ну вот Вас то и спрашивают, в чем именно проблема возникла? То что Вы пишете Бота - это понятно. Что у Вас работает не так как ожидается?

Comment: Проблема в том что я новичок, в Гугле по поводу моего вопроса инфы нет, вот и спрашиваю каким образом можно реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, используя tgApi, получать список сообщений из заданных канало, после проверять есть ли в них это слово и соответственно сохранять их